# How can I UPDATE (multiply by 5 and not simply replace) nested revenue fields within BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

I'm trying to use DML in BigQuery to update nested revenue fields.
The challenge is, that I do not want to simply replace the value of the revenue, but multiply it with a specific factor instead.

For just replacing I've found:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
    (SELECT AS STRUCT transaction.* REPLACE ( 1 AS transactionRevenue)) AS transaction
  )
  FROM UNNEST(hits) as transactionRevenue
)
WHERE true
```

But I would like to have something like:

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (
    (SELECT AS STRUCT transaction.* REPLACE ( (transactionRevenue*5) AS transactionRevenue)) AS transaction
  )
  FROM UNNEST(hits) as transactionRevenue
)
WHERE true
```

This approach doesn't work.
Error Message: No matching signature for operator * for argument types: STRUCT, INT64. Supported signatures: INT64 * INT64; FLOAT64 * FLOAT64; NUMERIC * NUMERIC at [4:48]

Answer (score 1):

Below should work

```
UPDATE `project.dataset.table`
SET hits = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(
    (SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(5 * transactionRevenue AS transactionRevenue) 
      FROM UNNEST([transaction])
    ) AS transaction
  ) 
  FROM t.hits
)
WHERE true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mikhail!